# how to change the edit text position dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am new to Android. I am trying to implement photo tagging application where we can tag the faces like facebook photo tagging. I am able to find the faces and draw the rectangles over faces.

But I am trying to place an `EditText`(to write name) at face recognized rectangle when the user touches those rectangles. And once it is done I need to disable the `EditText` and need show `TextView` (name). Please find code below and help me.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    myEditTet = new EditText(this);

    myView custom = new myView(this);
    layout.addView(myEditTet);
    myEditTet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // layout.addView(myTextView);
    // myTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layout.addView(custom, params); // Of course, this too
    setContentView(layout);

}

private class myView extends View {

    private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
    private int numberOfFace = 5;
    private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
    private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
    float myEyesDistance;
    int numberOfFaceDetected;

    Bitmap myBitmap;

    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.face3, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
        imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
        imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
        myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
        myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                numberOfFace);
        numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
            android.media.FaceDetector.Face face = myFace[i];
            PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
            face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
            myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
            dx = (int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance);
            dy = (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance);
            dz = (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance);
            dt = (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance);
            canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance), myPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        myEditTet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (event.getX() > dx && event.getX() < dz && event.getY() > dy
                && event.getY() < dt) {
            Log.i("SARDAR", "RECT TOUCH 1111");

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have done it by this way...

```
params.setmargin(left,top,right,bottom);

layout.addView(myeditText,params);
```

arguments are of int types

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can u please tell me where we need to write this statement,because i need to add edit texts when user clicks on on screen , i think we cant write in oncreate() method.

Comment: @user369932 you are welcome :) you can definitely write it in onCreate() just below this..

    LayoutParams params =new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: and make edittext visible whenever you want (in your case may at onClick)